# dismissViewControllerAnimated prevents new UIViewController from showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to replace one `UIViewController` with another, However I have ecountered a problem.

If I write this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
//load currentProjectListViewController
currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This almost works, however the view just blinks and nothing happens.. no new view is loaded or anything, I have put a break point inside `currentProjectListViewController` and the thread never makes it there.

however if I do this.

```
//load currentProjectListViewController
currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

`currentProjectListViewController` loads perfectly fine. however I am worried about whats hapening with the previous view? is it stuck there in memory? or is it gone?

my question is how can I dismiss it from memory as well as site without stopping my next view from appearing.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Describe your view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Think static views. no connection to the other. Normally I use navigation controllers if im making something with more than 2 views. but this app has 5 and my boss would like me to make them static. so at any point if the app closes from memory I can open it straight to the same view it was on with no worry about how the other views are going to react.

Answer (score 0):

No, the second way is the correct way as far as I see it. In the first method you're asking the VC to dismiss before a new VC is presented. This would be there is no view, which wouldn't happen. 
Bu presenting a new VC, the old VC won't be retained in memory as the nature of the view is that it only uses memory when it is in view. I hope this make makes sense.

Comment: okay I this sounds like it makes sense to me. I am goig to try and do some more debugging to see if this is not the case..

Comment: actually, I have been doing some debugging just now and im not sure your statment is correct. as when i load the old view back up it never even calls any of the methods in it like viewdidload. So its like its just sitting there till the view i load is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting the new view controller in the completion handler of the dismiss method call:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self; //Need to have a weak reference to self to prevent retain cycle.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
    [weakSelf presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: for some weird reason if i put a break point inside the curly brackets the thread never enters that part of your code. I have tried it several times  and it just will not load the new view.